# GeoTiff specs for coordinate transformation definition

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I would like to define a GeoTiff coordinate transformation by a set of GCPs only. The intention is to publish the GeoTiff as a coverage in GeoServer.

However if I specify tie points only, GeoServer complains that I also need to specify the scale tag, which then results in only one tie point used, eg no inclination or shearing. Is this normal? Can't I use GCPs alone for projection?

On the other hand I could define a transform, but the transformation is rather limited compared to let say a set of 10 GCPs.

Thanks for any help,

Thomas

Comment: Well here's the answer from Andrea Aime, who is a contributor to GeoServer (I posted the equivalent question on the geoserver mailing list):


Nope, it is not supported at the moment. We're waiting for someone to
implement or fund such functionality.


You can use gdalwarp and make it rectify the images out of the GCP,
this way you get both good accuracy and the usage of a single
transformation

Comment: You might want to post it and accept it. That way, people will know that the issue has been resolved.